# Why is there water dripping through my soffits?

Tags: water, leak, roof, soffit

[image: This picture was taken directly below the roof in the 1st picture. You can see it is soaking wet.]This picture was taken directly below the roof in the 1st picture. You can see it is soaking wet. I do have a skylight on that roof but that has been replaced and sealed repeatedly. I always blamed the skylight but now I am wondering about the drip edge.

Comment: One tight shot of a piece of flashing doesn't provide much info re a roof leak. Is the soffit leak directly below this flashing? Pls provide some overall pictures of the roof and soffits indicating where the leak is occurring. Water leaking from a soffit could have traveled a long way down a rafter before surfacing. Provide some detail.

Comment: Also, you should [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know how this site works.

Comment: If the leak is in only one spot removing one of the soffit panels may give you a good idea of the source of the leak.

Comment: That flashing looks totally wrong to me higher than the roofing, a gap it looks like someone designed it to leak.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry for your frustrations but what a sh!t job by this roofer. What even are those flaps hanging in the gutter; drip edge backup plan?

I'd like to see more angles of your roof line but I think this picture will illustrate how water is flowing on your roof.

[image]

If you're comfortable with ladders then grab a hose and pour water on your roof while you record the flow. You should quickly see whether things are working properly.

If my illustration is accurate then expect your fascia to rot in the next few years.

For the record, water dripping from your soffits is not normal. Keep investigating until you find the source and do everything in your power to make the roofer properly fix it. Presumably you paid at least $10,000 for this new roof so if they suggest patch-work such as silicone or some mastic then be aware that they are trying to avoid doing it right.

Comment: Over $25,000 this cost me. There is snow on the roof at the moment and the hose will not be on for many months. I understand what you are saying in the picture. I am looking forward to being able to look at it a bit better when we get better weather. Thanks so much for the advice.